# Parsing line-based structure (ray tracer) without using too many vars

Tags: parsing, scala

I want to parse a file in scala (probably using JavaTokerParsers?). Possibly without using too many vars :-)

The file is the input for a ray tracer.

It is a line based file structure.

Three types of lines exists: empty line, comment line and command line

The comment line starts with # (maybe has some whitespace before the #)
Command line starts with an identifier optionally followed by a number of parameters (float or filename).

How would I go about this. I would want to parser to be called like this

val scene = parseAll(sceneFile, file);

Sample file:

```
#Cornell Box
size 640 480
camera 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 45
output scene6.png

maxdepth 5    
maxverts 12
#planar face
vertex -1 +1 0
vertex -1 -1 0
vertex +1 -1 0
vertex +1 +1 0

#cube
vertex -1 +1 +1
vertex +1 +1 +1
vertex -1 -1 +1
vertex +1 -1 +1

vertex -1 +1 -1
vertex +1 +1 -1
vertex -1 -1 -1
vertex +1 -1 -1


ambient 0 0 0
specular 0 0 0
shininess 1
emission 0 0 0
diffuse 0 0 0

attenuation 1 0.1 0.05

point 0 0.44 -1.5 0.8 0.8 0.8
directional 0 1 -1 0.2 0.2 0.2

diffuse 0 0 1
#sphere 0 0.8 -1.5 0.1


pushTransform

#red
pushTransform
translate 0 0 -3
rotate 0 1 0 60
scale 10 10 1
diffuse 1 0 0
tri 0 1 2
tri 0 2 3
popTransform

#green
pushTransform
translate 0 0 -3
rotate 0 1 0 -60
scale 10 10 1
diffuse 0 1 0
tri 0 1 2
tri 0 2 3
popTransform

#back
pushTransform
scale 10 10 1
translate 0 0 -2
diffuse 1 1 1
tri 0 1 2
tri 0 2 3
popTransform

#sphere
diffuse 0.7 0.5 0.2
specular 0.2 0.2 0.2
pushTransform
translate 0 -0.7 -1.5
scale 0.1 0.1 0.1
sphere 0 0 0 1
popTransform

#cube
diffuse 0.5 0.7 0.2
specular 0.2 0.2 0.2
pushTransform
translate -0.25 -0.4 -1.8
rotate 0 1 0 15
scale 0.25 0.4 0.2
diffuse 1 1 1

tri 4 6 5
tri 6 7 5
tri 4 5 8
tri 5 9 8
tri 7 9 5
tri 7 11 9
tri 4 8 10
tri 4 10 6
tri 6 10 11
tri 6 11 7
tri 10 8 9
tri 10 9 11
popTransform

popTransform

popTransform
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I've pushed it too hard for the one liner but that's my take (although idiomatic it might not be optimal):

First, `CommandParams` represents a command along with its arguments in a list format. If no arguments then we have `None` args:

```
case class CommandParams(command:String, params:Option[List[String]])
```

Then here's the file parsing and construction one liner along with line-by-line explanation:

```
val fileToDataStructure = Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines()    //open file and get lines iterator
  .filter(!_.isEmpty)   //exclude empty lines
  .filter(!_.startsWith("#"))   //exclude comments
  .foldLeft(List[CommandParams]())    //iterate and store in a list of CommandParams
  {(listCmds:List[CommandParams], line:String) =>   //tuple of a list of objs so far and the current line
                    val arr = line.split("\\s")   //split line on any space delim
                    val command = arr.head    //first element of array is the command
                    val args = if(arr.tail.isEmpty) None else Option(arr.tail.toList)   //rest are their params
                    new CommandParams(command, args)::listCmds   //construct the obj and cons it to the list
  }
  .reverse    //due to cons concat we need to reverse to preserve order
```

A demo output iterating through it:

```
fileToDataStructure.foreach(println)
```

yields:

```
CommandParams(size,Some(List(640, 480)))
CommandParams(camera,Some(List(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 45)))
CommandParams(output,Some(List(scene6.png)))
CommandParams(maxdepth,Some(List(5)))
CommandParams(maxverts,Some(List(12)))
CommandParams(vertex,Some(List(-1, +1, 0)))
...
CommandParams(pushTransform,None)
CommandParams(pushTransform,None)
CommandParams(translate,Some(List(0, 0, -3)))
...
```

A demo of how to iterate through it to do actual work once loaded:

```
fileToDataStructure.foreach{
  cmdParms => cmdParms match {
    case CommandParams(cmd, None) => println(s"I'm a ${cmd} with no args")
    case CommandParams(cmd, Some(args))=> println(s"I'm a ${cmd} with args: ${args.mkString(",")}")
  }
}
```

yields output:

```
I'm a size with args: 640,480
I'm a camera with args: 0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,1,0,45
I'm a output with args: scene6.png
I'm a maxdepth with args: 5
I'm a maxverts with args: 12
I'm a vertex with args: -1,+1,0
...
I'm a popTransform with no args
I'm a popTransform with no args
```

Comment: Thanks :-) That's better than what I have now. Sorry for the late response, was still hoping for a JavaTokenParsers solution :-)